# Does not work break in powershell script with Get-Content tail

Tags: windows, shell, powershell, batch-file, jenkins

I have bat-script, that writes in txt file few lines.

```
set logfile=D:\my_job\out.txt
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo completed >>%logfile%
echo completeD >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo ***Completed*** >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
echo wwe >>%logfile%
```

And i have script to stop execution of my job, if i see `***Completed***`

```
Get-Content D:\my_job\out.txt –Wait | ForEach-Object {$_ ; if($_ -eq "***Completed***"){break} }
```

But it does not stop my job execution.
Also, i tried this:

```
Get-Content D:\my_job\out.txt –Wait | ForEach-Object {$_ ; if($_ -Match "***Completed***"){break} }
```

And in output i see:

```
parsing "***Completed***" - Quantifier {x,y} following nothing.
At C:\Users\jenkins\AppData\Local\Temp\jenkins4007901642048080451.ps1:1 char:138
+ ... t -Wait | ForEach-Object {$_ ; if($_ -Match "***Completed***"){break} ...
+                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException
```

Can you help me please, how can i resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

This command will add a space at the end of the line:

```
 echo ***Completed*** >>%logfile%
```

so your check `$_ -eq "***Completed***"` will fail.

Either remove space in `echo` or add space in comparison string.

Regarding the error with `-match`: it operates with regular expressions and `***Completed***` is an incorrect regex due to use of `*`.